# Can I combine AND and OR conditions

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I am using the below method to query using Spring Data JPA.

```
findByUpdatedGreaterThanAndFromEmailOrToEmailInOrderByUpdatedAsc(final long updated, final String email, final String to);
```

The query is always passes because of the OR condition.

My intention was  findBy(**UpdatedGreaterThan**)And(**FromEmailOrToEmailIn**)OrderByUpdatedAsc

Is there anyway to do the same in Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data jpa - How to combine multiple And and Or through method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788856/spring-data-jpa-how-to-combine-multiple-and-and-or-through-method-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [@Query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based) annotation to manually craft a mongodb [query](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/query/) to properly enforce the logic of your search criteria.

Something like (I leave the ordering part to you):

```
@Query(
    "{ $and : [ { 'updated' : { $gt: '?0'} }," + 
               "{ $or : [ { 'email' : '?1' }, { 'to' : '?2' } ] }")
findByUpdatedGreaterThanAndFromEmailOrToEmailInOrderByUpdatedAsc(final long updated, final String email, final String to);
```

where ?0, ?1, ?2 are placeholders for your findBy method arguments.

Comment: Did the same. Was hoping there was some syntax for the method name to do the same. @choda Thank you.