# In Spring Data JPA how to achieve Where predicate with AND and OR together

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

using JapRepository - SPring Data JPA, how to handle this case : (AnB) U (CnD) operation where braces plays vital role.

```
findAllByAAndB() => WHERE A = ? AND B = ?
findAllByCAndD() => WHERE C = ? AND D = ? 
findAllByXOrY() => WHERE X = ? AND Y = ?
<How to achieve this clause> => WHERE  ( A = ? AND B = ? ) OR ( C = ? AND D = ? )
```

Comment: JPA generally doesn't support union[some providers might]; have you tried the last query in proper form, what exception you are getting, incorrect results, no results, query not parsing etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data jpa - How to combine multiple And and Or through method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788856/spring-data-jpa-how-to-combine-multiple-and-and-or-through-method-name)

Answer (score 1):

In such scenario you can use JpaSpecificationExecutor, following is the way to implement.

1. Extend your repo with JpaSpecificationExecutor.

   `public interface EntityRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Entity>`
2. Create a Specification class and implement your query using Predicate

   `Predicate predicateAnd1 = cb.equal(entity.getA(), entity.getB());`

   `Predicate predicateAnd2 = cb.equal(entity.getC(), entity.getD());`

   `Predicate predicateOr = criteriaBuilder.and(predicateAnd1, predicateAnd2);`
3. Then in your service class use something like following

   `repo.findAll(entitySpec.getSpec());`

The following page has a good example.

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/