# valid query creation using the combination of keywords(And,Or)

Tags: spring-data-jpa

```
Below is my entity

@Entity
@Table(name = "xxxxx")
public class xxxx implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1935611638367876605L;

@Column(name = "PHONE1")
private long phone1;

@Column(name = "PHONE2")
private long phone2;

@Column(name = "SSN")
private String ssn;

}
```

My requirement is a combination of SSN && (phone1 || phone2)
   is this a valid query creation using the keywords(And ,Or)
   findBySSNAndPhone1Orphone2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data jpa - How to combine multiple And and Or through method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788856/spring-data-jpa-how-to-combine-multiple-and-and-or-through-method-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query("select x from Xxx x where x.ssn = ?1 and (x.phone1 = ?2 or x.phone2 = ?3)")
List<Xxx> findBySsnAndPhone1OrPhone2(String ssn, String phone1, String phone2);
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation ?

Comment: @alexbt https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query (or you meant somth. else?..)