# How to generate crudrepository findBy method signature with AND and OR Conditions?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How can I generate findBy method corresponding to below query in JPARepository?

```
select * from person where name=?1  and eff_dt < ?2 and (exp_dt >?2 OR exp_dt IS NULL)
```

Comment: is your query above correct? recheck. and also show your entity class

Comment: You create a method, choosing the best method name you can think of, and you annotate it with `@Query("<the jpql query>")`. Queries derived from method names are fine for simple stuff like findByName(). They're not for more complex queries like the one you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data jpa - How to combine multiple And and Or through method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788856/spring-data-jpa-how-to-combine-multiple-and-and-or-through-method-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can technically do it. But its better to avoid it.

Assuming you entity class is like

```
class Person {
  String name;
  Integer effDt;
  Integer expDt;
  // getters and setters
}
```

your method name will be

```
findByNameIsAndEffDtLessThanAndExpDtGreaterThanOrNameIsAndEffDtLessThanAndExpDtIsNull(String name, Integer effDt, Integer expDt, String name2, Integer effDt2);
//name and name2 will be same & effDt and effDt2 will be same.
//Boolean Algebra: A(B+C) = A.B + A.C
```

As you can see this is needlessly complicated and difficult to understand. Use a native query instead.

Answer (score 1):

select * from person where name=?1  and eff_dt < ?2 and (exp_dt >?2 OR exp_dt IS NULL)
Assuming the entity class by the names of the variables

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private Date eff_dt;

    private Date exp_dt;

}
```

The query can be

```
public final static String FIND_ALL_PERSONS="select s from Person p where p.name=:name   and p.eff_dt < :eff_dt and (exp_dt > : exp_dt OR exp_dt is null)";
@Query(FIND_ALL_PERSONS)
List<Person> findAllPersons(@Param("name")String name,@Param("eff_dt") eff_dt,@Param("exp_dt") Date axp_dt);
```