# How to name methods in spring data with and-or in the same query

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I want to have a method which searches for data on the basis of status and (SellerId or BuyerId). The following method name doesnt work for me and gives me an error: No parameter available for part status SIMPLE_PROPERTY (1): [Is, Equals] NEVER.
What is to be corrected in the method signature? Seller and Buyer are two separate tables each having a field id.

findByStatusIsAndSellerIdOrStatusIsAndBuyerId(status, id)

Comment: The Spring data method names get ridiculous with more than a couple of properties. I would suggest using the `@Query("...")` annotation to manually define and then you can call your  method whatever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data jpa - How to combine multiple And and Or through method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788856/spring-data-jpa-how-to-combine-multiple-and-and-or-through-method-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findByStatusIsAndSellerIdOrStatusIsAndBuyerId(status, id)
```

expects 4 parameters for the four conditions.

You also should never use a derived query with `AND` and `OR` because precedence gets pretty confusing at best.

So pick a name that you like and use a `@Query` annotation to specify the query to use.

`SELECT x FROM X x where x.status = :status and (x.seller.id = :id or x.buyer.id = :id)` should be close to what you need.