# Spring Data JPA "OR" operator on multiple columns

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have the following entity structure:

```
public class Car {

    private String make;
    private Integer price;
    private Integer year;
}
```

I want to search for all cars made by **HONDA** whose price is higher than **50,000** or made in **2019**.

The query I need to come up with is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE make='HONDA' AND (price>50000 OR year=2019);
```

I tried the following method but it produces the query without the brackets and hence producing the incorrect results.

```
List<Car> findAllByMakeAndPriceGreaterThanOrMake(String make, Integer price, Integer year);
```

Alternatively, I can use `@Query` to write my own query but wanted to see if there's an existing way to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data jpa - How to combine multiple And and Or through method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788856/spring-data-jpa-how-to-combine-multiple-and-and-or-through-method-name)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
List<Car> findByMakeAndPriceGreaterThanOrYear(String make,Integer price, Integer year)
```