# JPA Multple Query using AND/OR Precedence

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have three fields in an entity, lets say A, B and C. I am using JPA query method `findByAAndBOrC` for a query. I want to find entries by `A AND (B OR C)`. But I am not sure whether `findByAAndBOrC` is giving `A AND (B OR C)` or `(A AND B) OR C`. What is the precedence order, and how to set precedence in JPA multiple query methods for a group as we do using parentheses in sql?

Comment: Why not simply run the query and look at the result (or the generated SQL statement)?

Comment: Did you try the first answer (unaccepted) in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788856/spring-data-jpa-how-to-combine-multiple-and-and-or-through-method-name?

Comment: @aksappy I didn't check that question, thanks, it solved my issue. Should i close the question?

Comment: @please_don't_hurt It was autogenerated comment. It is created every time question is marked as "close as duplicate".