# Hibernate combine AND and OR query

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following hibernate query

```
findByUserOrReaderAndIdInAndStatusNotIn
```

the actual query generated is

```
WHERE user=? OR reader=? AND (id in (?, ?)) AND (status not in (?, ?))
```

but what I actually need is

```
WHERE (user=? OR reader=?) AND (id in (?, ?)) AND (status not in (?, ?))
```

How to properly create the findBy method?  I cannot use @Query cause this method is generic.

Comment: My guess is that you'll have to use an explicit query with the `@Query` annotation.  The JPA provided methods are for convenience only, there are usually instances where they won't do exactly what you need.

Comment: "@Query" can be used for generic purpose also. @Query gives you more control than the method name derived queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring data jpa - How to combine multiple And and Or through method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788856/spring-data-jpa-how-to-combine-multiple-and-and-or-through-method-name)

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the generics, so I did the following and it works.

```
@Query("from #{#entityName} t where (t.user = :user or t.reader = :reader) and (t.id in (:ids)) and (t.status not in (:statuses))")
```