# Spring Data JPA existsBy and Or condition

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

For example I have this query:

```
select * from table where column1 = val and ((column2 is null and column3 = false) or
(column2 is not null and column3 = true))
```

How to create Spring data jpa for this using

```
existsByColumn1...(Integer val)
```

Comment: Does this help to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788856/spring-data-jpa-how-to-combine-multiple-and-and-or-through-method-name ?