# two condition inside and operator jpa

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm wondering how to convert this query to JPA:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u " +
        "WHERE u.clList IN (:clList)" +
        "AND ( u.enName like CONCAT('%',:searchBar,'%') OR u.frName like CONCAT('%',:searchBar,'%') ) ")
List<User> getAll(List<Long> clList,String searchBar);
```

I try this but doesn't work

```
List<User> findAllByClListInOrEnNameIsLikeIgnoreCaseOrFrNameIsLikeIgnoreCase(Long clList,String enSerach,String frSerch);
```

My main issue is how to do this

```
AND ( u.enName like CONCAT('%',:searchBar,'%') OR u.frName like CONCAT('%',:searchBar,'%') )
```

Comment: Check out answers to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788856/spring-data-jpa-how-to-combine-multiple-and-and-or-through-method-name) i personally don't think that it's worth the hassle and having these unreadable method names, but it's always better to know how to do it anyway.

Comment: I totally agree @Kamil Bęben, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

make sure when you are going to the next line you should leave space between like here after `"WHERE u.clList IN (:clList)"` you didnt leave a space which will return a syntax error. Also practice putting `WHERE` condition and `AND` condition inside () like where (condition) and (condition). Also you can directly use `LIKE %:var:%` without concat though thats just a suggestion not a mistake. Otherwise i cant see any errors. Hope this helps

Comment: My JPQL , its works and fine , but I want to convert it as a jpa function like this ( findAllByClListInOrEnNameIsLikeIgnoreCaseOrFrNameIsLikeIgnoreCase )